# Can not understand Python expression

Tags: python, lambda

I encoutered some Python function and totally cannot understand its meaning, nor did I know how it works.

```
def test(data, bot):
    return reduce(lambda a, b: a or b, [i in data['message'] for i in
        ['地震了吗', '地震了么', '地震了?', '地震了？', '地震了吧']])
```

I know the result is if `data['message']` (which is a string value) contains any of these strings `['地震了吗', '地震了么', '地震了?', '地震了？', '地震了吧']`, function test will return true.

Comment: Don't post the code in question title.

Comment: Gah, my eyes. That's not the friendliest piece of python..

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Sorry, really don't know any better way to express this question without ambiguity

Comment: @MartijnPieters I personally hate this code, and think some smart pants is trying really hard to show off

Comment: Smart people do not use reduce

Answer (score 13):

You are looking at a list comprehension; for each `i` it will calculate `i in data['message']`.

If you were to write this out in a loop instead, it would be:

```
tmplist = []
for i in ['地震了吗', '地震了么', '地震了?', '地震了？', '地震了吧']:
    tmplist.append(i in data['message'])
```

So, for each string in the list, test the boolean expression `i in data['message']` and add the result (`True` or `False`) in `tmplist.

The `reduce()` function then returns the equivalent of:

```
tmplist[0] or tmplist[1] or tmplist[2] or ... or tmplist[len(tmplist)-1]
```

but expressed in a more tortuous manner. `reduce(lambda a, b: a or b, sequence)` starts with `sequence[0]` and `sequence[1]` as `a` and `b`, then takes the result of the `lambda` as `a` and the next element in `sequence` as `b`, and repeats this until all elements in senquence have been processed.

A friendlier way to write this would be to use [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) instead:

```
return any(i in data['message']
    for i in ['地震了吗', '地震了么', '地震了?', '地震了？', '地震了吧'])
```

`any()` is actually more efficient; it'll run the generator and will stop immediately when a match is found; if `data['message']` contains `'地震了吗'` only one test will be performed.